# Making Open Action only enabled on visible polygons

Tags: display, actions, categorized-renderer

I have a shape with polygons with `Date` field (`YYYY-MM-DD`). The shape is displayed as Categorised according to year (`substr("Date",1,4)` and I can switch polygons on an of according to year.
I have an action to open an image of a polygon (`cmd /c [%path%]` that works fine.

The problem is that it is also active on an empty area when polygons are not displayed.
I know I could make an additional field with year only and categorise display on year field.

Is it possible to make an Action responding only on visible polygons if they are categorised with `substr` function?